# Are Ruby odd-numbered releases stable and for production? (eg. 1.9.1, 1.9.3)

Tags: ruby

I used Ruby many years ago and am back hopefully to stay. I recall from several years ago reading that odd-numbered releases of Ruby (eg. 1.9.1, 1.9.3, 1.9.5) are meant for development and that even releases (eg. 1.9.2, 1.9.4) are meant to be production stable. Is this (still) the case or is the latest "stable" as per the Ruby website the way to go?

I've never developed a project as grand as Ruby so I don't know if there are rules for releases that should be followed. Any enlightenment on this topic would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Only 1.9.1 was considered unstable, but that's not by design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is in fact true that odd-numbered releases *were* unstable in the past. (However, note that "odd-numbered" refers to the *minor* number, not the *tiny* number, i.e. 1.1.x, 1.3.x, 1.5.x and 1.7.x were unstable development releases.)

This was changed with Ruby 1.9 for a very simple (and very embarassing) reason: there are *tons* of Ruby scripts as well as shell scripts (including the scripts that the Ruby maintainers *themselves* use to automate the development, testing and releasing of Ruby) out there, which simply assume that the major version is a single digit. They would simply *break* otherwise, mostly because they did things like

```
if RUBY_VERSION > '1.6.3'
```

which *fails* for `'1.10.0'`, because the *string* `'1.10.0'` is lexicograhically *smaller* than the *string* `'1.6.3'`.

As a result, it was decided to give up the distinction between odd-numbered and even-numbered releases, and make the next stable release 1.9, because that was easier than convincing everybody that their scripts are broken.

So, the 1.9.0-x series of releases corresponds to 1.9.x under the *old* numbering scheme (i.e. a series of development releases in preparation of the next release) and the 1.9.(x > 0) series of releases corresponds to 1.10.(x-1), i.e. 1.9.2 is really 1.10.1. (Well, except that 1.9.1 was a botched release, so it is more like a 1.10.0-pre and 1.9.2 is 1.10.0 and 1.9.3 is 1.10.1.)

Also, Ruby 2.0 is intended to be fully backwards-compatible, which means that it's really 1.12 ... does that clear up any confusion? :-)

So, in summary: Yes, it *used* to be true (but in a different way than you thought), but it is *no longer* true, and hasn't been true since the 1.7 series which ended with the release of Ruby 1.8.0 in August of 2003, over *eight years* ago.

Comment: I was wondering if I was the only one who thought Ruby 2.0 was merely Ruby 1.x with a overflow error.! Also, one thing that irks me is that some people claim that Ruby 1.9.1 was never meant to be a stable release. :(

Answer (score 5):

Nope, that's not the case. I don't think it was ever the case with ruby. 1.8.6 and 1.8.7 were considered stable, as are 1.9.2 and 1.9.3.

You might be thinking of Linux kernels, that's how they do it there.

Comment: Linux has given up on this scheme even longer than Ruby has.